# Flask backend not responding to JS frontend

Tags: python, flask, web-applications

I want to able to send data from a Javascript frontend to a Flask python backend, and have the flask backend return the data.

> problem is that even though I can see the http post request arrives the post request is failed and nothing happens.

frontend:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function()
{
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/dostuff",{url:15},function(data,status){
alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I want this to send the data to the server hosted at 127.0.0.1:5000

the backend:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dostuff')
def add_numbers():   
   a = request.args.get('url')   
   return str(a)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello world"
```

nothing happens when the button is pressed even though the command line in which the flask server is running shows this when i press the button:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2018 15:51:43] "POST /dostuff?url=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Can you please check what does your browser developer console, Networking tab shows when you click button? I'm interested in reply from the server.

Comment: @Dragin It says: 2127.0.0.1:5000/dostuff:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)                             
 and then:                                                                                                        
  Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:5000/dostuff: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Flask only accept `GET` method for you routes (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/)

If you want to send POST data you have to change `@app.route('/dostuff')` to `@app.route('/dostuff', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`